# Android source code compile failed to build some targets (07:03 (mm:ss))

Tags: android-source

I am trying to compile the Android source code, but i am having issues, i hope someone can help me out because i can't seem to work it out. I am also not too sure if i am building the right flavour since i want to build one for tv boxes specifically, rk3318. Thanks in advance, with kind regards!
**first i ran this**

```
o@o-MS-7C70:~$ cd aosp1/
o@o-MS-7C70:~/aosp1$ . build/envsetup.sh
o@o-MS-7C70:~/aosp1$ lunch armv8-eng

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
TARGET_PRODUCT=armv8
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.2.0-20-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-23.04
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SD1A.210817.036.A8
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
o@o-MS-7C70:~/aosp1$ m -j10
```

**this was the last block before it failed:**

```
checkvintf I 05-03 20:27:38 169563 169563 VintfObject.cpp:58] getDeviceCompatibi
lityMatrix: Reading VINTF information.
checkvintf I 05-03 20:27:38 169563 169563 HostFileSystem.cpp:43] Fetch 'out/targ
et/product/armv8/system/vendor/etc/vintf/compatibility_matrix.xml': OK
checkvintf I 05-03 20:27:38 169563 169563 VintfObject.cpp:64] getDeviceCompatibi
lityMatrix: Successfully processed VINTF information
20:27:43 ninja failed with: exit status 1`

#### failed to build some targets (07:03 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I tried rerunning the commands, searched the error, checked the forums and even tried reinstalling ubuntu

Comment: You probably need to look further up from the end of the log to find the failure; AOSP build often continues printing messages after the failure due to the number of simultaneous threads running. Search specifically for "FAILED: " in caps like that or even just "error".